# How to use iprintf in c++

Tags: c++, devkit, devkitpro

How can I use any command really (in c++ programming with Devkit Pro for NDS) to simply print a variably rather than text to a specific location? Here's what I have that prints text:

```
iprintf("\x1b[1;20HHello");
```

Comment: It's the same as normal `printf`, no?

Comment: Is this meant to be an ASCII escape sequence? If so, I think you're missing a `'0'`  before `'x'`: `"\0x1b[1;20HHEllo"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out later that for both iprintf and printf, this is a way to do it:

```
 iprintf("\x1b[%d;%dHText goes here...", y, x); //the x and y are reverse because that is how printf works
```

Comment: That is how to print to a variable's location and
`printf("%d",p)` for an integer (this case p), along with `printf("%s",string)` for a string/const char.

Answer (score 2):

You can also manipulate the console directly (including window it and have multiple consoles to print to).

```
PrintConsole* pc = consoleDemoInit();

pc->cursorX = 10;
pc->cursorY = 10;

printf("hi");
```

Here is a bit more detail:

http://libnds.devkitpro.org/a00107.html